# PHP won't grab email addresses from MySQL database to display in html doc

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a weird question. Is there any reason I can't display an email address I polled from a MySQL database?

Polling the database:

```
$AE_item = mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT AEmail FROM heac2013 WHERE cid =' . $heac);
if (!$AE_item) {
    $AEmail = 'Error reading data: ' . mysqli_error($dblink);
}
while ($AErow = mysqli_fetch_array($AP_item)) {
    $AEmail = $AErow['AEmail'];
}
```

same code works when polling a field that does not contain an email address, such as querying for a phone number

```
$AP_item = mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT APhone FROM heac2013 WHERE cid =' . $heac);
if (!$AP_item) {
    $APhone = 'Error reading data: ' . mysqli_error($dblink);
}
while ($AProw = mysqli_fetch_array($AP_item)) {
    $APhone = $AProw['APhone'];
}
```

at the end of all these polls there is an html document containing echo tags encased in

```
 <?php echo $AEmail; ?> and <?php echo $APhone; ?>
```

I'm confused. Ever other bit of data shows in the html page (name, address, phone, image of person), but the email addresses are being returned as blank.

When checking the database with PHPmyadmin the fields are there, and the sql query works, but within my php/html documents the emails don't display.

Is there something this n00b is missing?

Comment: Don't you mean `<?php echo $AEmail; ?>`

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php echo AEmail; ?> and <?php echo APhone; ?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php echo $AEmail; ?> and <?php echo $APhone; ?>
```

Comment: ...it already was. Read my post please. The error was in other variable names. I have fixed it on my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$AE_item = mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT AEmail FROM heac2013 WHERE cid =' . $heac);
```

to

```
$AE_item = mysqli_query($dblink, 'SELECT AEmail FROM heac2013 WHERE cid ="' . $heac . '"');
```

for both queries.

Reason : 
your variable $heac may or may not be a number. (depending on your SQL design)

(I assumed that the error pointed by j08691 and nickhar weren't the solution)

Comment: The variable is declared as an integer, but at least your answer makes sense. The problem was fixed. In copy-pasting multiple blocks of code I forgot to change 3 variable names.